# ControlPaint.DrawBorder() draws only top and left sides

Tags: c#, winforms, border

When painting on a control, `ControlPaint.DrawBorder(...)` draws only top and left sides of the control. `ControlPaint.DrawBorder3D(...)` does the same.

```cs
ControlPaint.DrawBorder(e.Graphics,
                ClientRectangle,
                Color.Black, 5, ButtonBorderStyle.Inset,
                Color.Black, 5, ButtonBorderStyle.Inset,
                Color.Black, 5, ButtonBorderStyle.Inset,
                Color.Black, 5, ButtonBorderStyle.Inset
                );
```

This draws only top and left sides! Even if I change `ClientRectangle` to

```cs
new Rectangle(ClientRectangle.X, ClientRectangle.Y, ClientRectangle.Width - 10, ClientRectangle.Height - 10)
```

It still does the same. Is there any way to draw border on all sides?

Comment: Make sure `ClientRectangle` is referring to the Button's `ClientRectangle`, not the Form's. Try with `ControlPaint.DrawBorder(e.Graphics, [Button].ClientRectangle, Color.Black, ButtonBorderStyle.Inset);` first.

Comment: Unless this is a custom control that is. In this case, inflate the `ClientRectangle` (using negative values) based on the width of the border (e.g., `var rect = this.ClientRectangle.Inflate(-5, -5)`). You should specify where `e.Graphics` comes from.

Comment: Copy/Paste typo: `var rect = this.ClientRectangle; rect.Inflate(-5, -5)`

Comment: I tried inflating the rectangle. Also, I can move the control and border stays bound to the control I'm moving. `Inflate` actually changes X and Y, but you need to change only Width and Height.

Comment: Oh! it works now. I changed `ClientRectangle` to `((Control)sender).ClientRectange` and it works! It is strange though: the X and Y of border were bound to the control I'm moving, but Width and Height were from the Form...

Comment: That's because `(X, Y)` is `(0, 0)`, when considering `Control.ClientRectangle` :) (So, the relative position/Location is always* correct-ish) (* not always...)

Comment: Oh, I understand now, Thanks!